# Nested forEach in Java 8 throws an exception

Tags: java, java-8

**EDIT**
its worked

```
        group.getUsers().forEach(user -> {
        user.removeGroup(group);
        privilegeRepository.findAll().stream().
                filter(privilege -> privilege.getName().startsWith(slugname.toUpperCase()))
                .forEach(privilege -> {
            user.removePrivilege(privilege);
            privilegeRepository.delete(privilege);
        });
    });
```

I have nested for-loops and I want to replace that for-loops with a forEach:

```
for (User user : group.getUsers()) {
     user.removeGroup(group);

     for(Privilege privilege : user.getPrivileges()){

         if (privilege.getName().startsWith(slugname.toUpperCase())){
             user.removePrivilege(privilege);
             privilegeRepository.delete(privilege);
         }
     }
}
```

to

```
group.getUsers().forEach(user -> {

     user.removeGroup(group);

     user.getPrivileges().stream().filter(privilege -> privilege.getName().startsWith(slugname.toUpperCase()))
          .forEach(privilege -> {
              user.removePrivilege(privilege);
              privilegeRepository.delete(privilege);
          });
});
```

And it throws a exception:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: the complete stack trace would be useful, so we can see what line throw the exception

Comment: `user.getPrivileges()` vs `privilegeRepository.findAll()`: doesn't look like the two are doing the same thing

Comment: Instead of using streams here it might make more sense to use an old fashioned iterator which you can call `remove()` on to get the privilege removed from the user's privileges.

Comment: You cannot call `user.removePrivilege` while iterating over `user.getPrivileges`. You need to make a snapshot copy to iterate over.

Comment: So in this case no need replace for-loops with a forEach ?

Comment: It is interesting why you do not get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` in the first example (with the nested for-loops). I think `user.removePrivilege(privilege);` still can make modification on the collection that you are iterating in the same time.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't get error first example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what it says. In the loop, you are modifying the array you are looping through, which is not allowed in Java foreach loops.

I'd suggest you create a temporary array in the outer foreach loop (where you loop the users) for the privileges and delete the items from that array, instead of the user's privilege array. So instead of `user.removePrivilege(privilege);` you should use something like `temp.remove(privilege)`.

After the inner loop, you can clear the user's privilege array and add the items in the temporary array.

Comment: So in this case no need replace for-loops with a forEach ?

Comment: no, you can keep the forEach

Comment: @zblash the for-loops have exactly the same problem. The iteration policy does not change when you use a Stream, so you’re using a collection not allowing modifications while iterating and it’s a pure coincidence if you did not hit the exception previously.